# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (Typescript)

Tags: typescript2.0, vuejs2

I'm trying to make [this](https://github.com/locoslab/vue-typescript-component-example) example work in typescript. But for some reason I get an error when I run it: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

[image]

I don't really understand why I am getting this problem (I am quite new to Typescript and Vue).

The reason I use

```
import Vue = require('../libs/vue/index')
import * as vts from '../libs/vue-typescript-component/vue-typescript-component'
```

is because my node_modules are not a part of the project, so I link to the files in my libs folder, which as you can see is included in the wwwroot

Comment: `import * as Vue from '../libs/vue/index'` will probably workaround the issue. The problem is that `require` function is only defined in Node.js and you seem to work in browser environment.

Comment: I tried that line now but it gives me the same error. It seems like `tsc` compiles it to `
var Vue = require("../libs/vue/index");
var vts = require("../libs/vue-typescript-component/vue-typescript-component");`